# How does sort function works in algorithm in C++, and how to improve this code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

Here is my homework challenge:

> Question: Write a program for a prom night, in which a girl can only dance with a taller boy.

What I am trying to do:

- `b` no. of boys, `g` no. of girls
- Stored in vector
- Sort the vector
- compare heights and get result like

  ```
    Boy      Girl     Can dance?
  1 98       90       Yes
  2 90       91       No
  3 85       82       Yes
  4 78       75       Yes
  5 70       72       No
  ```

What I want to know:

- How can I improve this code.
- How does sort function works? what type of sorting does it uses? can it be applied on arrays as well?

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int b,g,i,j,h,r,count=0;
    vector<int> boys, girls;
    //Input -no. of boys and girls and their heights
    cout<<"Enter number of Boys: ";
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"Enter number of Girls: ";
    cin>>g;
    if(g>b)
    {
        cout<<endl<<"NO! All girls can't dance, because no. of boys is less'";
        exit(1);
    }
    r=b-g;
    cout<<endl<<"Start entering height of each boy in Centimeter...."<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<b;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Height of Boy "<<i+1<<" : ";
        cin>>h;
        boys.push_back(h);
    }

    cout<<endl<<"Start entering height of each girl in Centimeter...."<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<g;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Height of Girl "<<i+1<<" : ";
        cin>>h;
        girls.push_back(h);
    }

    //sorting heights of boys and girls
    //boy
    cout<<endl<<"After sorting boys according to height"<<endl;
    sort(boys.begin(),boys.end(),greater<int>());
    for(i=0;i<b;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Height of Boy "<<i+1<<" : "<<boys[i]<<endl;
    }
    //girl
    cout<<endl<<"After sorting girls according to height"<<endl;
    sort(girls.begin(),girls.end(),greater<int>());
    for(i=0;i<g;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Height of Girl "<<i+1<<" : "<<girls[i]<<endl;
    } 
    for(i=0;i<g;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<boys.size();j++)
        {
            if(boys.at(i)<=girls.at(i))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }   
    }

    if(count==0)
    {
        cout<<endl<<"All girls can dance!\nWhile "<<r<<" boys won't have a partner!";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"All girls can't dance!";
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: you really should provide the inputs, expected outputs and what you really get. I get a headache when reading your question.

Comment: You're pushing the boy onto `rem` if there's any girl he can't dance with, even if there are other girls that he *can* dance with. You need to loop through all the girls, and if he couldn't dance with any of them, push him onto `rem`.

Comment: This is not a good question, the title is not good and the question is really too long (the problem is not abpout dancing nor gender but about programming). You should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) please.

Comment: This seems to be one of the most common programming mistakes I see among inexperienced programmers.

Comment: @Mukul Why aren't you coding for the output in the format you posted?

Comment: `std::sort` takes an optional comparison function. See the documentation.

Comment: Now it got even worse...

Comment: Please don't change your question in a way that invalidates existing answers. Ask a new question if you have a new question and don't find the solution.

Comment: @Baum what else do u want me to do.. that was my 2nd question which i can't post now because of this one...

Comment: @MukulChauhan Read the [ask] and post good questions from now on. For new users, the right to post questions is a scarce resource by design and trying to trick this design by abusing the edit function is not okay. Now you either wait or try to find the answer yourself, it probably exists somewhere on this site.

Comment: @Baum i don't own a pc, can't edit it from my mobile. I will have to wait for 4-5more hrs to be in my college

Comment: @BaummitAugen can you check the question now, if its correct ?

Comment: isn't it correct now ? @BaummitAugen

Comment: @MukulChauhan That's not for me (alone) to judge, editing a closed question places it in the reopen queue where the community (3k+ useres) decides whether or not it is fine now.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the issue is in this line:

```
for(i=0;i<rem.back();i++)
```

`rem.back()` is retrieving the last element of the `rem` vector, which is storing indices. see [the documentation on Vector.back()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/back/).

What you should have on that line is something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < rem.size(); i++)
```

That should help. I don't know if it will fix all problems, but that's one thing I noticed.